# Rewording the on-topic help section

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In the [light of recent confusion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/637/is-possible-to-open-questions-to-learn-german) about what is on-topic here, I'd like to have the [on-topic help section](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) reworded.

Currently our on-topic site contains a very generic and way too unspecific text:

> German Language & Usage Stack Exchange is for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

As an example of a better definition I'd like to mention [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

#### Please vote on suggestions, since we need a community consensus to perform changes like this.

Comment: A clarification would definitely be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [German Language Help](https://german.stackexchange.com/help) section was now updated with suggestions given here:

- ["What topics can I ask about here?"](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

To see where stuff is going, I have started from the [current text](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Changes are bold:

> German Language Stack Exchange is for speakers **and learners** of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translations.
>
> **Before asking, please consider the following points to ensure that your question is welcome and on-topic here:**
>
> - [Look around](https://german.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before.
> - **If your question could be answered by a dictionary or grammar book, consult one before asking. Explain why this did not help you when asking your question.**
> - **Do not ask for translations of specific sentences, which may not be of general interest. We can not be a translation service.**
> - **Translations requests from German should be restricted to cases where a profound knowledge of German is needed for understanding a phrase or an idiom.**
>
> **Questions in both, English and German are welcome.** It is also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://german.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for German Language & Usage Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.
>
> For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) **and [“How do I ask good, on-topic questions for translations or about differences?”](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences).**

Comment: Removed chat as propsed place for a translation service. This may not be what we want. On-topicness should be roughly the same on the site, and in chat. We may be much more loose in chat but we should not direct people there for translation requests.

Comment: See http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for an update.